# TWILIO_APP_TOKEN same as auth token?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

While reading the PHP Twilio documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-lumen-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests), there is a reference to "`TWILIO_APP_TOKEN`".

Is this the same as the Auth token or it is something else? Could this be a relic of documentation that was not updated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the AUTH_TOKEN. The document should state that instead of "TWILIO_APP_TOKEN".

Confirmed it by testing the code with the AUTH_TOKEN successfully.